# Installing CAS Server : A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/surefire/util/NestedCheckedException

Tags: maven, cas, maven-surefire-plugin

I am not familiar with Tomcat, but I followed a tutorial. Everything run well until I launched the maven clean package.
The output gives me the following error :

```
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test': Unable to load the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/surefire/util/NestedRuntimeException
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.NestedRuntimeException
```

I have checked on the net and it seems this error is common, but none of the methods indicated worked : I have rm -Rf the .m2/repository/org/

My pom.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sso.mydomain.com</groupId>
<artifactId>local-cas</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                         <configuration>
                             <warName>cas</warName>
                         </configuration>
                    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <cas.version>3.5.2</cas.version>
</properties>

    <repositories>
     <repository>
              <id>ja-sig</id>
              <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ </url>
         </repository>
    </repositories>
```

My conf : ubuntu, maven 2.2.1
I have spent an hour in this. any idea ?

Comment: I also tried to force a more recent version of surefire by adding this to my pom.xml :

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <parallel>methods</parallel>
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

without success. But this version is loaded

Comment: I faced the same issue while using Maven 2. Using Maven3, the issue was gone. Ubuntu has two packages, Maven (latest) and Maven2 (latest 2.x). You could try uninstalling  `maven2 ` and installing the  `maven ` package using `apt-get `